# associate existing fields from class methods sequelize

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have this two Sequelize models generated from the CLI

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var ticket_sold = sequelize.define('ticket_sold', {
    ticket_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    bus_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    departure: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    destination: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    passenger_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    amount: DataTypes.FLOAT,
    status: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    is_deleted: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        
      }
    }
  });
  return ticket_sold;
};
```

and

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var locations = sequelize.define('locations', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    status: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    is_deleted: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        
      }
    }
  });
  return locations;
};
```

I need to associate the Departure and Destination to the Id of the location field. I could not just use the has many/belongsto as it creates another field.

I tried doing 
tickets_sold.departure.belongsTo(models.locations,{
          onDelete:"CASCADE",
          foreignKey:{
            allowNull:false
          }
        })
but it was of no use.

How can I associate the two fields with the location table?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`targetKey` property](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#belongsto)

From the docs :

> The target key is the column on the target model that the foreign key column on the source model points to. By default the target key for a belongsTo relation will be the target model's primary key. To define a custom column, use the targetKey option.

So in your case you will need to do something like :

```
tickets_sold.belongsTo( models.locations, { targetKey: 'departure' } );
tickets_sold.belongsTo( models.locations, { targetKey: 'destination' } );
```